# Exponents and bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, solution-verification, exponentiation

I have some doubts in understanding the necessity of some steps in the following situation. While solving an algebraic problem, I came across an expression of the following type, where I have to solve for ${a}$:
$${x^{a-1}}{y^{a-1}} = {x^{a}}{y^{-1}}$$
I see that there are corresponding like terms on both sides of equation, so I equate the powers (This is what I generally think of.) which gives ${a-1 = a}$, and ${a-1 = -1}$. The second equation implies ${a = 0}$, but is contradicted by the first one.

My first question is: am I right till here? If yes, then is this a coincidence that ${a = 0}$ was not a solution? (I think so.)

More importantly, my second question is: should I go for taking the logarithm on the original equation now, as a greedy approach to get some solution (which, assuming that ${x}$ and ${y}$ obey the required constraints, gives ${a} = {\log_y x}$)? Is this a pitfall if, after getting that contradiction (${a \neq 0}$), instead of using logarithm I claim that there is no solution for ${a}$?

Comment: You can explore this equation here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%28a-1%29y%5E%28a-1%29%3Dx%5Eay%5E%28-1%29

Comment: You have real solutions for example when $a=0,x=1,y<0$ etc.

Comment: The existence of solutions will depend on what values of $x$ and $y$ are required to satisfy the equation. For example, is it supposed to be true for all real $x$ and $y$? For all positive $x$ and $y$? For all nonzero $x$ and $y$? For all complex $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes, wolframalpha tells one solution as ${a > 1, x = 0, y > 0}$; here I can't understand how it came up with ${a > 1}$ though.

Comment: It was not mentioned in the question about the constraints on ${x}$ and ${y}$, but I am working mostly with reals. @MPW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, no, your deductions are incorrect; in general, you cannot simply equate the powers on each variable. For example, consider $x = 4$, $y = 2$, and $a = 2$. Then $$x^{a-1} y^{a-1} = 4 \cdot 2 = 8 = \frac{4^2}{2} = x^a y^{-1},$$ but obviously, the powers of $x$ and $y$ on the RHS and LHS of the equation aren't equal. As a side note, one of your deductions $a - 1 = a$ is very clearly impossible; in the future, use these as red flags to indicate whether or not you're doing something wrong.

Your intuition, however, to use a logarithm to solve for the value of $a$, was correct. If we rearrange the equation, we get $$y^a = x,$$ and taking $\log_y$ on both sides yields $a = \log_y {x}$. If you're unconvinced that $a = \log_y{x}$ satisfies your equation, try coming up with values of $x, y$, and evaluating the powers using your calculator.